# Print all (non-hidden) files in any subdirectory of the current directory that end with .c

Tags: unix

Print all (non-hidden) files in any subdirectory of the current directory that end with .c (immediate subdirectories only, not subdirectories of subdirectories). Do not use find.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a homework, but nonetheless: `echo */*.c` (assuming there's at least one such file and scanning hidden subdirectories is not required).

Comment: `lpr */*.c 2> /dev/null || true`

I think I remember that class.